# SharePoint time has delay about 11 min

Tags: sharepoint-server

my sharepoint time is different from normal which it is delay about 11 min. the time zone is set to +8

how to config it to normal?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate the SharePoint servers and client are synchronizing time correctly from the Domain Controllers. If the time is >5 minutes off, manually adjust the time, but validate that time is synchronizing via `w32tm`.

[Configuring the Windows Time Service in an Active Directory Forest – A step by step with a Contingency Plan](https://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2014/04/26/configuring-the-windows-time-service/)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to different Time zones one by one and see what time you are getting.

Refer to the following article about setting proper SharePoint Time Zone for users:

https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-time-zone/

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint displays the time on you SharePoint Servers, check the time on your severs operating System.

Comment: my screen is capped from sharepoint server

Comment: Check all servers including the database server